# CSTheory or CS for a question on the existence of a specific research topic?

Tags: support

I want to ask if there exists someone who is working on the definition of a strictly more powerful formalism than the Turing Machine.

Is this question on a research level? Should I ask it on CSTheory or in CS or somewhere else?

Thanks.

EDIT: my interests are on a more divulgative-fashion, I am only an undergraduate that is new in the "world" of Computational Models :)

Comment: Topic-wise, [cstheory.SE]. Not sure if they'd want it, though: the answer is probably "yes", but where are you going with this? Do you want to read their work? Contact them? Work with them? Maybe hit the [chat of cstheory.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9446/theory-salon), but I'm not sure if that'll help.

Comment: Thank you for yor help. I'm only a Computer Science student who is facing basic topics in Theory of Computation and I found fascinating the Church-Turing thesis. I would like to know if there is someone brave enough who is trying to improve modern CS in that aspect and if so, learn the basic ideas about his formalism, obviously not at research-level but in a  more divulgative-fashion. I think It's better to edit the topic :)

Comment: Google "hyper computation".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to say whether it is a research-level question without seeing the question itself.

If you are working through an undergraduate textbook and it got you to wondering, odds are that this is more likely to be appropriate on CS.SE.  If you are doing research on theoretical computer science (e.g., reading research papers published in peer-reviewed conferences, collaborating on a research project with an established researcher), it might be more appropriate on CSTheory.SE.

Given your comment that you are looking to "learn the basic ideas about his formalism, obviously not at research-level but in a more divulgative-fashion", that definitely sounds like a question for CS.SE.  CSTheory.SE is for research-level questions about theoretical computer science.